# Работа с циклами wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Как ограничить количество постов в цикле.

```
 <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
 <?php the_title(); ?>
 <?php the_content(); ?>
 <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Дело в том, что я не могу понять логику, каким образом каждый пост можно вложить в карусель, например.

Comment: В чем основная проблема? Вы в основном цикле хотите задать ограничения или выполняете свой запрос, а потом хотите ограничить полученные посты?

Answer (score 2):

Вопрос на самом деле мало касается Wordpress. Нужно только добавить переменную `$postsLimit` и соответствующую проверку в `while`.

Например, если хотим задать ограничение в 10 постов:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : $postsLimit = 10; while ( have_posts() && $postsLimit-- > 0 ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php the_title(); ?>
<?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```